# Google contacts subgroup of a group of contact

Tags: google-contacts-api

There is a way to replicate a subgroup contacts structure via java api as like when someone import a csv in their contacts.

My contacts
->Co workers

etc...

How i can do this with the google contacts java api??'

Answer (score 0):

I can only point to these google pages:

[2009](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/-RaApHPNRhw)

[2012/13](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/OxqKu5hoDx4)

According to these discussions it was requested but is not implemented.

I use the work-around presented in the second link:

1. Create My contacts
2. Create My contacts.Co workers
3. Add contacts to the respective groups
4. Add all sub-group members to the parent-group

Since this is not supported by Google, I doubt there is a solution with their java API.